# Sending message to some of the clients subscribed on same topic in MQTT

Tags: mqtt

Is it possible to that two clients are subscribed to same topic in MQTT broker. And based on authorization, some of the massages are sent to one client and not other (subscribed on same topic).

Comment: Since it is a Pub-Sub model, the broker will not have the ability to choose the messages which it send to individual MQTT clients. If you need, you can have one common topic where the common data goes, and a second topic structure which can be authorised and send to specific devices as shown in the next answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No

Any number of clients can be subscribed to a given topic, but you can not limit which of those clients can receive messages on that topic on a per message basis. It is all the topic or none.

Comment: Oh, Actually, I was working on Azure Iot Hub which allows you to connect IoT device to hub through MQTT. And any server application can call method on any device. But azure provides single topic to subscribe to receive the messages on devices. This topic is same for all the devices. I dont know how they make it work then.

Comment: That is not pure MQTT,  Microsoft must have extended their broker some how.

Comment: Although it is not pure MQTT broker, but it still works on MQTT protocol, So do you mean that broker implementation (server side) is such that it doesn't work like regular MQTT broker.

Comment: That is pretty much what I said

Comment: Also worth pointing out. the MQTT protocol has no way to identify which client you would want to receive the message so the messages must be being submitted to the broker by some none MQTT mechanism, this is why I said it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct solution for this approach. But however I have a workaround for this solution.

Say you have two client with ClientId: 1 and 2
Say your topic structure is : `stackoverflow/data/{Client-ID}/sensor/ingress`

While defining the authorization parameter you can assert with the permission as `+/+/{Client-ID}/+/+`

This will make sure that, the topic structure will remain the same, but at the same time, the client will be able to publish and subscribe data only from their own topics.(topics which have their client-Id).

Since it is a Pub-Sub model, the broker will not have the ability to choose the messages which it send to individual MQTT clients. If you need, you can have one common topic where the common data goes, and a second topic structure which can be authorised and send to specific devices as shown here.

Comment: In that case the clients would not be subscribed to the same topic, each client would be subscribed to the topic containing their client id.